# JavaFX ComboBox - How to get different Prompt Text and Selected Item Text?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I've searched a bit, but couldn't find an answer. The Combobox is editable. How can I show different text in the Combobox prompt text and in the list of Objects below? In the list I want the toString method of the Object to be used, but when I select it, I want only one attribute of the selected Object to be shown in the prompt text.

How can I do this? Is it possible to display the value of an object differently in the prompt text field and in the list below?

An example of the usage would be with songs. Let's say I search a song by title, then it shows me the song with the title, composer and instrument below. When I select the song, I only want the title to be shown in the prompt text (because I display the composer and instrument Information somewhere else).

Comment: Do you want to use the text field of the editable ComboBox to filter the results that is displayed in the dropdown?

Comment: Note that the prompt text is the text displayed, if no item has been selected and thus is independent from any `toString` method of your items. This is most likely something like `Please select an item` and not the `toString` result for an item... Interpreted it as "text displayed in the TextField" in my answer below. If that's an incorrect interpretation, please tell me in a comment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`converter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#converterProperty--) that uses the short version for the conversion and a custom [`cellFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#cellFactoryProperty--) to create cells displaying the extended version:

```
static class Item {
    private final String full, part;

    public Item(String full, String part) {
        this.full = full;
        this.part = part;
    }

    public String getFull() {
        return full;
    }

    public String getPart() {
        return part;
    }

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ComboBox<Item> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Item("AB", "A"),
            new Item("CD", "C")
    ));

    comboBox.setEditable(true);

    // use short text in textfield
    comboBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<Item>(){

        @Override
        public String toString(Item object) {
            return object == null ? null : object.getPart();
        }

        @Override
        public Item fromString(String string) {
            return comboBox.getItems().stream().filter(i -> i.getPart().equals(string)).findAny().orElse(null);
        }

    });

    comboBox.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<Item>() {

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Item item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            // use full text in list cell (list popup)
            setText(item == null ? null : item.getFull());
        }

    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(comboBox);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```